# Django run custom management command on docker + Kubernetes env

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I have deployed my Django application on AWS using Kubernetes.
I am using docker containers to deploy my application. 
I have created the custom management command lets say

```
python manage.py customcommand
```

I want execute it on kubernetes level.

To get pods i am using

```
kubctl get pods
```

I am trying to find solution but not succeeded 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a shell in your running pod by using a command similar to the following:

```
kubectl exec -ti <podname> sh
```

From the shell prompt you get, you can run your administrative command.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make it automated in Jenkins?

Comment: If you want to integrate with your CI, I suggest running a dedicated pod, just to run your administrative task. That would be easier to automate with Jenkins